# Label caption changes only once

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to print out a table into a sheet which has an image with some activex labels on it. As the pages change, I want the label captions to change too and reflect the data in the table. But what is happening is that only the first page is getting printed and the others are not. My MsgBox seems to get the right data but during printing it is just printing the first page. Is it even possible to print out sheets within a for loop? I tried to run the code one page number at a time and it prints out just fine. But when I am looping through page numbers, it prints out only the first page over and over again.

Here's my code.

```
    Dim temp As String
    Dim rowlast As Integer
    Dim page As Integer

    rowlast = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'MsgBox WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((rowlast - 1) / 4, 0)
    For page = 1 To WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((rowlast - 1) / 4, 0)
        'Msgbox for first entry in current page
        Label1.Caption = Sheets("Data").Cells(((page - 1) * 4) + 2, 1)
        MsgBox Label1.Caption
        Label3.Caption = Sheets("Data").Cells(((page - 1) * 4) + 2 + 1, 1)
        Label5.Caption = Sheets("Data").Cells(((page - 1) * 4) + 2 + 2, 1)
        Label7.Caption = Sheets("Data").Cells(((page - 1) * 4) + 2 + 3, 1)
        Label2.Caption = Sheets("Data").Cells(((page - 1) * 4) + 2, 2)
        Label4.Caption = Sheets("Data").Cells(((page - 1) * 4) + 2 + 1, 2)
        Label6.Caption = Sheets("Data").Cells(((page - 1) * 4) + 2 + 2, 2)
        Label8.Caption = Sheets("Data").Cells(((page - 1) * 4) + 2 + 3, 2)
        Label9.Caption = Sheets("Data").Cells(((page - 1) * 4) + 2, 3)
        Label10.Caption = Sheets("Data").Cells(((page - 1) * 4) + 2 + 1, 3)
        Label11.Caption = Sheets("Data").Cells(((page - 1) * 4) + 2 + 2, 3)
        Label12.Caption = Sheets("Data").Cells(((page - 1) * 4) + 2 + 3, 3)
        Label13.Caption = Sheets("Data").Cells(((page - 1) * 4) + 2 + 3, 5)
        Label14.Caption = Sheets("Data").Cells(((page - 1) * 4) + 2 + 3, 5)
        Label15.Caption = Sheets("Data").Cells(((page - 1) * 4) + 2 + 3, 5)
        Label16.Caption = Sheets("Data").Cells(((page - 1) * 4) + 2 + 3, 5)
        Label17.Caption = Sheets("Data").Cells(((page - 1) * 4) + 2 + 3, 4)
        Label18.Caption = Sheets("Data").Cells(((page - 1) * 4) + 2 + 3, 4)
        Label19.Caption = Sheets("Data").Cells(((page - 1) * 4) + 2 + 3, 4)
        Label20.Caption = Sheets("Data").Cells(((page - 1) * 4) + 2 + 3, 4)
        'MsgBox "OK"
        Sheets("Card Print").PrintOut
    Next page
```

Here's my table:

[image]

Here's my output sheet:

[image]

Comment: Try adding a `DoEvents` just before printing.  Or toggle `ScreenUpdating` off and then on again.

Comment: Tried adding userform = doevents, didn't work.  
Also tried application.screenupdating = false and then true. Didn't work.

Comment: Seems Excel it's getting lost while looping, perhaps an [application.wait or sleep](http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-wait-and-sleep-functions/) would help to let the processor update the values for the printing?

Comment: Tried application.wait, not working. I have done similar things before but it involved updating cells and they used to work. The only difference this time is that I am trying to update label captions, i don't know why it is causing issues though.